# Hidden test cases failed in a c program to count number of digits

Tags: c, counting

I'm trying to solve a question in our C programming lab. This is a program about finding number of digits in a number.

I somehow managed to code the solution but the issue is that the hidden test cases always fail no matter what I do.

The main visible test cases pass the test without any errors but the hidden test cases always fail and I can't view them.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n < 1) {
        n = -n;
    }
    while (n > 0) {
        n /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", count);
}
```

and these are the test cases and their outputs
Test case 1:

Input: `12345`
Output: `Number of digits: 5`

Test case 2:

Input: `987654321`
Output: `Number·of·digits:·9`

These test cases run successfully without any errors but the hidden test cases, 4 of them, don't work.

Comment: test case: `-2147483648` (or `INT_MIN` in 32-bit machines). With `n = -2147483648;` doing `n = -n;` results in **Undefined Behaviour** ... usually `n == -n == -2147483648`.

Comment: It will report `0` when you enter `0`.

Comment: What is the expected minumum & maximum value of the "number"?

Comment: You could input a "string" (with `fgets()`) and count the digit characters instead... works for numbers like `-123456789012345678901234567890123456789` ... or simply read input character-by-character, ignore optional leading whitespace and minus sign, count digits until something invalid appears

Comment: It's unclear if you should count leading zeroes or not.

Comment: You are not checking return value of `scanf`: What if someone inputs non-number?

Comment: Try entering `QWERTY`....

Comment: OT: `n=-n;`  can be deleted if you do `while(n!=0){`

Comment: What is the actual problem statement (not your intepretation of it)? Along with any limits.

Comment: For any kind of programming problem, always identify the extreme and unusual cases, and make sure your solution works for all of them.  That can be tricky in the real world, but for an academic exercise or a machine-judged challenge the limits are normally laid out clearly for you.

Comment: @WeatherVane 

Write a C program to count the number of digits in a number.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The coding platform that our college uses is kind of retarded and bare bones. They don't mention any limits or anything. They just tell us to write "C program for X" and thats it.

Comment: Don't forget about floating point numbers (i.e. 3.14159).  Don't forget about handling an empty file as input.

Comment: Our college's coding platform doesn't push test cases like floating point numbers or empty files. They push similar input like the ones in the test cases but they don't mention the hidden test cases so nobody knows what's going on the inside.

Exceptions aren't a thing for this program

Comment: Then I think Weather Vane probably gave you the answer.  Zero is very valid number, which makes it a great hidden test case.

Comment: @SpaciousCoder78, you cannot write correct programs without knowing the definition of "correct".  In this case, that includes what kind or format of number is to be expected, including the numeric range or an equivalent.  It is not fair or reasonable to evaluate your program without giving you all the criteria in advance.  That does not mean disclosing all the test cases, but it *does* mean giving you enough information to write code that will pass them without guessing or trial & error.

Comment: Yeah but I can't really do anything about the lack of constraints. My college's platform is really retarded and I don't even know why they use it. I have to submit these programs by Friday and I have no clue what's failing the test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that the program input always consists of an integer in the range of type `int`, you still fail for 2 cases:

- `0` for which you output `0` instead of `1`
- `-2147483648` for which you have undefined behavior and most likely output `0` instead of `10`.

You can count the number of digits in both positive and negative numbers this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, count;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("not a number\n");
        return 1;
    }
    count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        count++;
        n /= 10;
        if (n == 0)
            break;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

If the user is allowed to type numbers in octal or hexadecimal format, you should use `scanf("%i", &n)` to recognise these alternative syntaxes.

Comment: `do count++; while (n /= 10);` ... but that can be left to the compiler :)

Comment: @pmg: yes this syntax is more compact and should generate the same executable code, but it does not pass my coding rules :)

Comment: What coding rule prohibits the use of `do` - `while`?

Comment: @thebusybee: my own coding rules restrict the use of `do` - `while` loops to macros encapsulating multiple statements.  The rationale for this is I have seen too many `do` - `while` loops with logic errors that seem to always come from delaying the test to the end of a task.  Try it for yourself: look for `do` - `while` loop in random open source projects on github and find the bugs.

Comment: Oh, I stumbled across the same kind of rational to prohibit the use of pointers. Instead indexes were advised, but no measures on the error rate was taken. <facepalm> I doubt that this kind of loop creates more errors than other kinds. Anyway, this is opinionated. ;-) I was just curious, thanks for the swift reply!

Comment: @thebusybee: yes, it is opinionated. Other kinds of loops cause programming errors too: for example `while` loops are more prone to messing with the index variable than `for` loops, yet I have seen coding rules that forbid `for` loops in favor of `while` loops.  In my experience, the observed failure rate in `do` - `while` loops is between 10 and 50% depending on the programmer's skill level, which fully justifies a ban IMHO.

Comment: It sounds like an environment with lots of beginners and without unit tests. :-D I'm coaching a special interest group for computer science for students from 5th grade on, and I never had that impression in more than 10 years. My condolences! My real job is in safety-relevant software development, where the things we fight are mainly missing and contradicting requirements.

Comment: @thebusybee `do count++; while (n /= 10);` also depends on an assignment in a conditional clause.  That is probably the single most bug-prone construct in C.  Expanding conditional processing as done in this answer so that every logical step is exposed and visible on a separate line is significantly more readable and understandable and therefore much less bug-prone than cramming as much functionality as possible into as few lines and characters as C syntax allows.  It's a lot more cost-effective and schedule-efficient to prevent bugs in the first place than any find-and-fix effort can ever be.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That was not the topic. ;-) Of course, `do { count++; n /= 10; } while (n != 0);` is a far better way, properly formatted.

Comment: @thebusybee: here is a question you answered 3 years ago with a typical  bogus `do` - `while` loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760488/letter-frequency-c-program/59764321#59764321

Comment: Since I did not write that loop, this proves what exactly? The error there was not using `do`-`while`, it was misunderstanding file input. This leads nowhere, I'm off.

Comment: @thebusybee: Of course no fault of yours, but you wrote *I never had that impression in more than 10 years*.  My take is the OP would have had to rethink the logic of the loop had they not used the `do` - `while` logic... There are countless examples like this. I'm off too :)

Answer (score 2):

I spot at least 5 unhandled edge cases

1. Zero will return `0`, but actually consists of `1` digit
2. Non-numeric input (e.g. 'abcd') is not handled
3. The minimum value of an int is not handled correctly.
4. Values smaller/larger than int's min/max
5. Numbers with decimals

Expanding on 3, the current approach handles negatives by converting them to positive numbers (`n=-n`).

The minimum value for int cannot be represented as a positive int.

With 64-bit int, the range of values that can be represented by int are

- MIN: -9,223,372,036,854,775,808
- MAX:  9,223,372,036,854,775,807

note the difference in the right most digit.

Expanding on that for 4, if an input is provided that cannot be stored in an int, it will be truncated and an incorrect answer will be given.

Given that the input is a string, it may be easier to verify that the string is a number, and then just return the number of digits in the string (minus `-` or `.` if present).

This handles numbers that are too large to fit into `int`, and checking if a string represents a number should be pretty straight forward.

- The first character may be `-` for negative numbers
- There may be at most one `.` for decimal numbers
- Every other character must be `0-9`

Comment: On many 64 bit systems, `int` is still 32 bit, but `long` is 64 bit

Comment: But the thing is our college's coding platform never tried to give us exception cases. If the test case is an integer and a finite number, then the hidden test cases will be finite and an integer, never anything else.

To test if its a size issue, I used long as well but the result is same

Comment: @SpaciousCoder78 part of this, in my opinion, is that a sense for edge cases and exception cases is itself a skill that should be practiced and developed. Real world software often runs into similar edge cases, many of which aren't in the original spec but must still be anticipated and handled.

Comment: *if an input is provided that cannot be stored in an int, it will be truncated and an incorrect answer will be given* Maybe. Formally, [that invokes undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10): "... if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined."  And that leaves the input stream in an unknown state, with no defined way to recover without loss of data.

Comment: @SpaciousCoder78 when the assingment says integer are they referring to a C `int` or the math integer. The latter is all whole numbers, including values much larger than what can be stored in a long. e.g. the integer made of ten thousand ones is easily represented as a string, but cannot fit into any numeric type in C.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I asked a fellow college mate about this program and he sent me the solution for it and all I had to do was use `n!=0` instead of `n>0` in the while loop and as well as use long long int.

This is the final code that actually works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    long long int n;
    int count=0;
    scanf("%lld",&n);

    while(n!=0){
        n/=10;
        ++count;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n",count);
}
```